# Update query with variable in querying part

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I want to write a mongodb update query in meteor with a variable in the querying part. It is an embedded document so I'm using the dot notation:

```
collection_name.update({"x.variable.z": "value"},new_value,{upset:true});
```

Since the `x.variable.z` is inside quotes, this doesn't work as expected.
How can I mention that `"variable"` is not a string but a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just constructing JavaScript objects, ie:

```js
var myVar = "somename";

var query = {};

query["x." + myVar + ".z"] = "value";
```

Which makes "query" look like this:

```js
{
    "x.somename.y": "value"
}
```